# Spring Boot 2 controller returns a callable but http response remains empty

Tags: spring-boot

I'm in the process of migrating a Spring Boot 1.5 project to Spring Boot 2.1.8 (JDK 1.8, Kotlin 1.3.50).

I have a few controllers whose methods look like:

```
@PostMapping("post")
fun post(@RequestBody input: String): Callable<JsonNode> {
    return Callable {
        requestAsJson(input)
    }
}
```

This works well in Spring Boot 1.5, without any further configuration. However with Spring Boot 2.1.8, the call does not fail but the HTTP response remains empty.

When I use start.spring.io to generate a minimalistic example, it works fine, so I guess that there is something wrong in my configuration.

When I enable debug traces for the Spring MVC, the final trace I get is:

```
[nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [{"data":{"...
[nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ASYNC" dispatch, status 200
```

So this looks fine to me, but still no response is received (using Curl or Postman to test).

I'm a bit at a loss now, since it was working like a charm in Spring Boot 1.5 and I'm trying to get a hint on how to get out of this issue.

Thanks for any help,
Damien

Comment: As of Spring Boot 2.1 there is now a pre-configured task-executor which is being used to handle those async requests. Before that this didn't exists and a default  task-executor would be used. Might be that that is interfering. I would expect the thread to be handled by a `task-*` thread (AFAIK that is the name used for the task-executor). Did you do some configuration for the async processing in your previous application?

Comment: In the Spring Boot 1.5 version, no particular setup is being done to support async requests and I thought it could stay this way.

Comment: Following some advices, I've added my own task executor in a `WebMvcConfigurer`:

     override fun configureAsyncSupport(configurer: AsyncSupportConfigurer) {
         val executor = taskExecutorBuilder.build()
         executor.initialize()
         configurer.setTaskExecutor(executor)
     }

But this does not change anything - the controller method is correctly called, the code runs correctly asynchronously on a separate thread and on completion, Spring MVC gets the result back.

However, the final answer returned to the client remains empty (Content-Length 0)

Comment: The asynchronous code is indeed managed by a `task-1` thread.

Comment: By doing some deep debugging in the Spring MVC layer, I can see that the correct message is written in the Servlet Output message, with correct content and all. However, something must happen later on in the MVC stack... Still debugging...

Comment: Ok... In the application, I had added a `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` filter (to add dynamically an ETag on every response). When I remove it, my requests are now processed normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had declared a `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` bean the following way in my `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@Bean
fun shallowEtagHeaderFilter(): ShallowEtagHeaderFilter {
   return ShallowEtagHeaderFilter()
}
```

While this was working fine in Spring Boot 1.5, this causes the controller async methods (returning a `Callable`) to not return any content any longer. Removing this bean for Spring Boot 2.1 restores a normal behavior.

I still need to seek a way to have my e-tag, but for now, this solves the present issue.

Comment: You need to add a `FilterRegistrationBean` and enable async processing for the filter.

Comment: Just enabling async in FilterRegistrationBean seems not have effect for ShallowEtagHeaderFilter